# How fast does the expected value of $\cos$ of a unif dist random variable converge to zero?

Tags: convergence, uniform-distribution

If $\theta$ is uniformly distributed in $\left[-\pi,\pi\right]$, how fast does the sample mean $\left<\cos\left(\theta\right)\right>$ converge to zero? Is the convergence speed proportional to $N$ realizations? $N^2$ realizations?

Comment: If the observations are independent, [basic properties of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) cover this entirely (variance of the mean is proportional to $\frac{1}{N}$. Standard error is therefore proportional to $N^{-\frac12}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta\sim U[-\pi,\pi]$. Denote the sample mean of $N$ observations by $S_N=N^{-1}(X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_N)$ (where each $X_i$ is an iid copy of $X$). Then the standard properties of variance imply that $\mathrm{Var}(S_N)=N^{-1}\mathrm{Var}(X)$, so convergence is $O(N^{-1})$.

You can get much better convergence with stratification - at least $O(N^{-3})$ according to (10.2) in this [book chapter](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~owen/mc/Ch-var-adv.pdf).

Comment: +1 -- but I don't understand the stratification proposal, because there doesn't seem to be anything to stratify on.  If you're going to exploit an assumption that $\theta$ is uniform, then it seems there's no point even to sampling: just report that the expectation of $\cos(\theta)$ is zero!  Some elucidation of your idea would therefore be welcome.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think that the knowledge that $\theta \sim U\left[-\pi,\pi\right]$ could be used to extract even more information on the speed of this convergence? Could $\mathrm{Var}[X]$ can be expressed as a function of $\mathrm{Var}[\theta]$ for example?

Comment: @unkown What sort of information on the speed of convergence? I'm not sure if there's anything else to say. $\mathrm{Var}(\theta)$ is a constant so your second question doesn't quite make sense to me as stated. I would be interested to know why you're looking into this question.

Comment: @S.Catterall, thanks again for your help. I am calculating a quantity that cannot be negative: $P^{2} = N \times a^{2} + N^{2} \times b^{2} \times \left<\cos(\theta)\right>$, where $a^2 > b^2$ and $N$ is the number of observations of $\theta$. I'm interested in values of $N$ of the order of $10^{11}$ however, I can only perform numerical simulations until, say, $N=10^{7}$ and occasionally I find $P^2 < 0$ so I was hoping to prove that, for $N$ sufficiently large, $P^2$ could never the negative.

Comment: @unkown Ah, I see. Unfortunately, no matter how large $N$ is, it is always possible that $\left<\cos(\theta)\right>$ can take a value close to -1, even if the probability of this happening is very small. So I don't think you could prove that $P^2$ is *never* negative in this situation.

Comment: @S.Catterall, I found a problem with my code. I was setting $N=10^{11}$ in the equation but was actually using $10^{7}$ as the number of $\theta$ points for calculating $\left<\cos(\theta)\right>$. This may be a problem. I will fix it and re-run the simulation with $10^7$ for both.